# how do I get MSProject 2013 to release the filter when I click on outline symbol (like MSProj 2003 did)?

Tags: microsoft-project

how do I get MSProject 2013 to release the filter (ie expand that branch fully) when I click on outline symbol (like MSProj 2003 did)?

Comment: Reading between the lines here..... I am guessing that what you mean is when you apply a filter and summary tasks are included in the filtered result, that you can no longer expand the summary task lines?  It works as expected when I do the following:

Show only outline level 1 tasks. (only summary tasks are visible)

Apply a filter (critical)

Expand the outline to show all critical tasks under the summary.


I am running Project 2013 with SP-1 and the latest CU.

Comment: To remove the filter, press F3

Answer (score 0):

Reading between the lines here..... I am guessing that what you mean is when you apply a filter and summary tasks are included in the filtered result, that you can no longer expand the summary task lines? It works as expected when I do the following: Show only outline level 1 tasks. (only summary tasks are visible) Apply a filter (critical) Expand the outline to show all critical tasks under the summary. I am running Project 2013 with SP-1 and the latest CU.
To remove the filter, press F3

Comment: To be clearer: What I meant was the in MSP2003 if the outline symbol was clicked..it would remove the filtering in that branch and fully expand that level. It seems as 2013 doesnt have that ability and it was quite useful. Thx

Comment: The filter persists when you expand the summary level task - it is a change from previous releases.